# how to resolve invalid parameters value for origin

Tags: android, hybrid-mobile-app, google-signin

I am trying my mobile application login through google account.

I got this error **invalid request and invalid parameter value for origin:missing authority:file://**. How to resolve it can any one please help me.

I am trying to checking my application in android mobile i got this below error.

[image: error in mobile]

[image: error in desktop]

```js
var CLIENT_ID = '349212001841-0o5cf26ah1g7fc4ufsfa1unk0ph3qoab.apps.googleusercontent.com';

var SCOPES = [ 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly' ];

function checkAuth() {
 gapi.auth.authorize({
  'client_id' : CLIENT_ID,
  'scope' : SCOPES.join(' '),
  'immediate' : true
 }, handleAuthResult);
}

function handleAuthResult(authResult) {
 alert("success")
 var authorizeDiv = document.getElementById('authorize-button');
 if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
  authorizeDiv.style.display = 'none';
  loadGmailApi();
 } else {
  authorizeDiv.style.display = 'inline';
 }
}

function handleAuthClick(event) {
 alert("failure")
 gapi.auth.authorize({
  client_id : CLIENT_ID,
  scope : SCOPES,
  immediate : false
 }, handleAuthResult);
 return false;
}

function loadGmailApi() {
 gapi.client.load('gmail', 'v1', listLabels);
}

function listLabels() {
 var request = gapi.client.gmail.users.labels.list({
  'userId' : 'me'
 });

 request.execute(function(resp) {
  var labels = resp.labels;
  appendPre('Labels:');

  if (labels && labels.length > 0) {
   for (i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
    var label = labels[i];
    appendPre(label.name)
   }
  } else {
   appendPre('No Labels found.');
  }
 });
}

function appendPre(message) {
 var pre = document.getElementById('output');
 var textContent = document.createTextNode(message + '\n');
 pre.appendChild(textContent);
}
```

```html
      <div data-role="page" id="loginPage">
       <div data-role="content" style="padding: 15px">
        <h1 id="fb-welcome"></h1>
     <label for="text">User Name:</label><input type="text" name="text" id="unL">
     <label for="text">Password:</label><input type="password" name="text" id="pwdL">
     <a href="#dashboardPage" data-role="button" id="appLogin()">LOGIN</a>
     <a href="#" data-role="button" onclick="fbLogin()">via Facebook Login</a>
       <a href="#" data-role="button" id="authorize-button" onclick="handleAuthClick(event)">via Google Login</a>
    </div>
      </div>
           
      <div data-role="page" id="dashboardPage">
    <div data-role="header" id="header" data-position="fixed">
     <h3>DashBord</h3>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content" style="padding: 15px">
        <a href="#" data-role="button" onclick='Logout();'>LogOut</a>
       </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: can you share your project? the primary problem you are facing is that you can't pass the redirect url like `file://path/localfile.html`

Comment: yes yoel i can share you--https://www.dropbox.com/s/mh2iq7dzcdpmpxt/LoginSN.zip?dl=0

Comment: You can do so with dropbox, google drive, github etc. Make sure it's public so I can access it, then post the link

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/mh2iq7dzcdpmpxt/LoginSN.zip?dl=0

Comment: I'll take a look at it and ask for more information if needed

Comment: where i have to pass redirect url